# Eclipse RCP : Can I show a hyperlink IN a tooltip?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to show a tooltip on an SWT image with a hyperlink. Please note, that I dont want to show a tooltip for a Hyperlink. It is the otherway. I want to have a hyperlink in a tooltip.

The user should be able to click on the hyperlink in the tooltip. Is it possible in Eclipse RCP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Have a look at the **[`org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/window/ToolTip.java.htm)** class and its [various implementations](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse/jface/3.5.0/org/eclipse/jface/window/ToolTip.java#) (click on the "Hierarchy tab").